# single mysql query for choosing 25 records (9+16) using union all and based on 2 different conditions

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I need to fetch 25 records using mysql out of which first 9 must be based on the descending order of `likes` count (**chosen randomly**) from 200 top appreciated and balance 16 **randomly** from the remaining items (**excluding 9, that are already filtered**). Is it possible to do this using a single mysql query? Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my query...

> (SELECT * FROM (SELECT tiles.*,users.first_name,users.last_name,    users.mosaicname,users.country,users.city,users.state,users.profile_image,COUNT(tile_appreciations.tile_id) AS appreciation_count FROM `tiles` LEFT JOIN `tile_appreciations` ON `tile_appreciations`.`tile_id` = `tiles`.`id` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `tiles`.`user_id` LEFT JOIN `user_settings` ON `user_settings`.`user_id` = `tiles`.`user_id` WHERE `tiles`.`view_mode` = 'PB'  AND `users`.`status` = 'Y' AND `tiles`.`moved_stat` = '1' AND `user_settings`.`public_profile` = 'Y' GROUP BY `tiles`.`id` ORDER BY `appreciation_count` DESC LIMIT 200) as t1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9) UNION ALL (SELECT tiles.*,users.first_name,users.last_name,users.mosaicname,users.country,users.city,users.state,users.profile_image,COUNT(tile_appreciations.tile_id) AS appreciation_count FROM `tiles` LEFT JOIN `tile_appreciations` ON `tile_appreciations`.`tile_id` = `tiles`.`id` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `tiles`.`user_id` LEFT JOIN `user_settings` ON `user_settings`.`user_id` = `tiles`.`user_id` WHERE `tiles`.`view_mode` = 'PB'  AND `users`.`status` = 'Y' AND `tiles`.`moved_stat` = '1' AND `user_settings`.`public_profile` = 'Y' GROUP BY `tiles`.`id` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 16)

Comment: have you tried something? you can add those information along with. To answer your question `Is it possible using a single mysql query`, `yes`, it is possible

Comment: please see the query that i have tried

Comment: select * from tiles where id <10 order by likes desc union  select * from tiles where id >=10;

Comment: select * from tiles where id <10 order by likes desc union  select * from tiles where id >=10 and id<=25;

Comment: Hi Sugumar...thank you for the response...the pblm is, tiles can be deleted. So there may be chances that the tile with id < 10 may not exists.

Comment: Could you add table structures? And maybe some dummy data? I see your joining on multiple tables and without this extra info it's hard to come up with a perfect solution

Comment: select * from tiles  limit 9 order by likes desc union select * from tiles limit 9,16 order by rand();

Comment: did this work or didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if using `UNION ALL` is a hard requirement, but SQL already has a very good system for filtering out results from the first query in the second query: it is called `UNION`. You can choose the remaining 16 by taking the union of 9 of the best 200 and 25 of the whole set and then limiting the total result to 25. I'm assuming here that `UNION` will remove duplicates from the second set and not the first.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT tiles.*,users.first_name,users.last_name, users.mosaicname,users.country,users.city,users.state,users.profile_image,COUNT(tile_appreciations.tile_id) AS appreciation_count 
        FROM tiles LEFT JOIN tile_appreciations ON tile_appreciations.tile_id = tiles.id INNER JOIN users ON users.id = tiles.user_id LEFT JOIN user_settings ON user_settings.user_id = tiles.user_id 
        WHERE tiles.view_mode = 'PB' AND users.status = 'Y' AND tiles.moved_stat = '1' AND user_settings.public_profile = 'Y' 
        GROUP BY tiles.id 
        ORDER BY appreciation_count DESC LIMIT 200
    ) as best200
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 9
) UNION (
    SELECT tiles.*,users.first_name,users.last_name,users.mosaicname,users.country,users.city,users.state,users.profile_image,COUNT(tile_appreciations.tile_id) AS appreciation_count 
    FROM tiles LEFT JOIN tile_appreciations ON tile_appreciations.tile_id = tiles.id INNER JOIN users ON users.id = tiles.user_id LEFT JOIN user_settings ON user_settings.user_id = tiles.user_id 
    WHERE tiles.view_mode = 'PB' AND users.status = 'Y' AND tiles.moved_stat = '1' AND user_settings.public_profile = 'Y' 
    GROUP BY tiles.id 
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 25
)
LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: Hi Spiny Norman, thanks...it worked for me. The only error was (Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias) and i fixed it by adding an alias.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I added the alias as well (assuming I aliased the correct select).